# Using Wireguard to expose Minikube services on a VM

Tags: fedora, qemu, nftables, wireguard

Due to hitting bugs running [Minikube on BTRFS](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/2411), I am running it now on a QEMU Fedora 35 guest VM on Fedora 35 host. I can use `ssh -fNL` port forwards to access the Podman diven network services in the guest, but I was hoping to be use something more sensible like a wireguard VPN to permit use of all published URL's on that subnet directly on the guest.

For example I have a service that can be accessed by a host browser address `http://localhost:32220` with port fowarding command `ssh -fNL32220:10.88.0.2:32220 192.168.122.122` however I wish to connect the host browser to the podman0 network address of `http://10.88.0.3:32220` through wireguard and I cannot.

Host Setup:

```
$ ip addr show dev wg0
12: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.0.0.1/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ ip addr show dev virbr0
5: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:92:ca:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ sudo cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <host private key string>
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = bxL6esqKWNjEcQ7hLeMTE/TYacztAu95f1shVfe7AjQ=
AllowedIPs = 10.88.0.0/16, 10.0.0.2/32
Endpoint = 192.168.122.122:51820

$ sudo cat /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf 
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Guest VM Setup:

```
$ ip addr show dev wg0
11: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.0.0.2/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ ip addr show dev enp1s0 
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c6:22:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.122/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft 2474sec preferred_lft 2474sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fec6:2284/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ ip addr show dev podman0
6: podman0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:07:63:90:3f:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.88.0.1/16 brd 10.88.255.255 scope global podman0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7cc5:35ff:fe52:509d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ sudo cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.2/24
SaveConfig = true
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <guest private key string>

[Peer]
PublicKey = Hwb/SeadMH/JbzelPyL7wvOY14Gf8owOcsDFMObD2lE=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/32
```

On the guest I have a service visible here (and as discussed above is available through ssh tunnels):

```
minikube service list
|----------------------|---------------------------|--------------|------------------------|
|      NAMESPACE       |           NAME            | TARGET PORT  |          URL           |
|----------------------|---------------------------|--------------|------------------------|
| default              | hello-minikube            |         8080 | http://10.88.0.3:32220 |
```

Finally I have added the wireguard service firewall port of `UDP/51820` to the `virbr0`

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --info-zone=libvirt
libvirt (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: virbr0
  sources: 
  services: dhcp dhcpv6 dns ssh tftp wireguard
  ports: 
  protocols: icmp ipv6-icmp
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
    rule priority="32767" reject
```

Any ideas (a) how to make this work or (b) how guest internal URI's could be made more friendly for me to test Kubernetes pods? Presently I've been using `waypipe` to forward a remote browser instance - a terrible hack :D

Comment: You should first validate the most basic use of your tunnel by also adding 10.0.0.2 to the AllowedIPs on the host so you can for example ping between 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2. Currently this won't work.

Comment: A good one @A.B - I've updated it and I've hit the respective `wg0` links with successful Pings and also run `sudo nmap -p51820 -sU 10.0.0.1` and confirmed `51820/udp open|filtered`. Sadly still doesn't permit the podman routes visible...

Comment: I've not anything with `nftables` as most of the examples are `iptables` and Fedora 35 doesn't use them. I'm wondering if that's causing issues...

Comment: `iptables -I FORWARD -i wg0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT` might do the trick.